# How do I get sin6_addr from an addrinfo?

Tags: c, sockets

My addrinfo pointer looks like this-

```
struct addrinfo hint, *res = NULL;
```

I then call get addrinfo.

```
hint.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  
ret = getaddrinfo(curhost, NULL, &hint, &res);
```

curhost is a character array. Doing

```
saddrv6.sin6_addr=*(res->ai_addr).sin6_addr
```

is giving me an error that says

**request for member 'sin6_addr' in something not a structure or union**. saddrv6 is a sockaddr_in6 struct. What is a good way to fill sin6_addr from info that I already have in res? New to C programming here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you're getting is because in:

```
*(res->ai_addr).sin6_addr
```

The `.` operator binds more tightly than `*`. You could change it to:

```
(*res->ai_addr).sin6_addr
```

which is probably what you meant, but the better way is to use the `->` operator:

```
res->ai_addr->sin6_addr
```

However, that still doesn't work because `ai_addr` has the useless opaque type `struct sockaddr *`, not `struct sockaddr_in6 *`. To fix this you need to cast it to a pointer to the type it actually points to:

```
((struct sockaddr_in6 *)res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr
```

At this point your code should work. However, ultimately the `ai_addr` member of `struct addrinfo` is not really meant to be accessed directly but rather used abstractly and just passed to functions like `connect`, `bind`, `sendto`, `recvfrom`, etc. At this point we're talking about a matter of style and good programming practices rather than correctness per the language, though.

Note that if you just want to get the IPv6 address for the sake of printing it as a string, the `getnameinfo` function with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag lets you do this in an abstract way without having to poke through the opaque `struct sockaddr *`.

Comment: Thanks! Casting to sockaddr_in6  got rid of the error